# Rails Active Admin Resource Association Belongs To

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In the select dropdown element it shows instead of the string for City:

```
<option value="1">#<City:0x007f850028b220></option>
```

Comment: show us the code you are using for this drop down.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your `City` model:

```
class City
  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

Replacing `name` with relevant attribute.